# Derive solution to $\int_{0}^{+\infty }\left( \frac{1}{1+s^{2}}\right) ^{\nu }ds$ where $\nu$ is noninteger real

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Can anyone derive the solution to
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty }\left( \frac{1}{1+s^{2}}\right) ^{\nu }ds$$
where $\nu$ is a non-integer positive real?
The derivation has been provided under [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222797) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362054) for integer $\nu$ with the solution

$$\frac{\left( 2\nu -2\right) !\pi }{2^{2\nu -1}\left( \left( \nu -1\right) !\right) ^{2}}$$

Expressed terms of the gamma function, this is,

$$\frac{\Gamma \left( 2\nu -1\right) }{2^{2\nu -1}\left( \Gamma \left( \nu\right) \right) ^{2}}\pi $$

I have spot checked to verify this generalizes the solution for real $\nu$, but this is not a proof.

Comment: Assuming $\operatorname{Re}(\nu) > \frac{1}{2}$ so that the integral converges, right?

Comment: Alternatively, in the first question linked by you, [Vue's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4222804/165060) using [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals#Another_relation_to_evaluate_the_Wallis'_integrals) can be derived through a substitution that transforms it into the Beta function. Using the [Legendre duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula), you can get it into the form you quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the beta function [$\int_0^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function) is known to [converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/427820/695196) for $a,b >0$. Also recalling that [$\Gamma\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma(z) = 2^{2-2\nu} \sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(2z -1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752895/695196) we get
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{1+s^{2}}\right) ^{\nu }\mathrm{d}s  &\overset{\frac{1}{1+s^2} = t}{=} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{1} t^{\nu- \frac{1}{2}-1}(1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}-1}\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\Gamma\left(\nu - \frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma(\nu)}=\frac{\pi\Gamma(2\nu -1)}{2^{2\nu-1}\Gamma(\nu)^2}
\end{align}
which converges for real $\nu >\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Note that the convergence region is for the integral and not for the final expression.

Comment: @Gary Did I hear *analytic continuation* ?!

Comment: Robert, it would be good to mention the use of Legendre's duplication formula in the last step.

Comment: Robert, apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: I tracked down your relationships in Grad. and Ryz. ed. 8:  8.380.1, 8.384.1, 8.310.1, and 8.335.1 and it looks tight. I have what I need, thanks.

Comment: @K.defaoite You did not understand what I meant.

Comment: @Gary I was just joking around.

Comment: @Gary, although the answer to "why ... $\Gamma$ so often works" answers the question, it answers it in a much more general and abstract way.  Robert Lee's answer is more concise and focused on the specific question, and uses simpler math. He doesn't even have to use complex numbers! It is the elegant solution.

Comment: @EdwardL.Ruden I thought you were interested in why replacing factorials with gamma functions should give a valid result in the general case. If not, then this answer is indeed better. Of course you may want to prove the formula for the beta function in terms of gamma functions.

Comment: @Gary, my need is simply to verify the equation for a paper. B in terms of $\Gamma$ is in Grad. and Ryz., so I can just cite it. If Robert Lee can provide me his middle intial, I can acknowedge him for "useful correspondence".